# Which flow metric is used to forecast - 'how many items will be done for the date'?

Tags: scrum, kanban, scrumban

I had following question in my [PSK assessment](https://www.scrum.org/professional-scrum-with-kanban-certification).

> Which flow metric is used to forecast - how many work items will be done for the date'?
>
> 1. Throughput
> 2. Work Item Age (WIA)
> 3. Cycle Time (CT)
> 4. Work in Progress (WIP)

Statement of the question is very tricky and hard to answer. Is it about forecasting for work items for a date (daily bases) or a forecast about specific date?

What can be the valid answer? Can any one help?

Here are reference docs:

- [4 Key Flow Metrics and how to use them in Scrum’s events](https://www.agilesparks.com/blog/4-key-flow-metrics-and-how-to-use-them-in-scrums-events/)
- [Kanban Guide for Scrum Teams](https://scrumorg-website-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/drupal/2018-04/2018%20Kanban%20Guide%20for%20Scrum%20Teams_0.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what is unclear. From your own reference:

> **Throughput**: The number of work items “finished” per unit of time.

So if you get asked: "How many units do you finish in an amount of time", this would be the obvious metric to make predictions. "We finish 5 units per day on average, so we should be able to finish around 30 by Friday next week".